# Ubuntu 12.10 Crashing

Tags: wubi, visual-artifacts

I used WuBi to install Ubuntu. I did this after I did a factory restore on my Windows 7 Desktop, and cleaned out unnecessary junk, defragged, etc. I also did some hardware tests, and everything seems to work. This is my first experience with Ubuntu or any Linux system.

It shows the grub screen where it's asks if I want windows or ubuntu, and I select Ubuntu. Then Ubuntu crashes at the login screen(or just prior to it), makes repeated beeping noises(in a loop), and has these strange diagonal lines through the screen.

Any suggestions on how to fix the problem?

Comment: Turns out I thought it was my network adapter, but it wasn't. I've only been able to get Ubuntu to boot up once out of about a dozen tries. If I had to guess, I would say it's my NVIDIA Geforce 6150SE nForce 430 that is causing the problem.

Comment: I can't boot with nomodeset. I can't get to it. I see grub , then > unbuntu, then I see a Ubuntu loading screen, then I see a login screen, then freeze, then purple screen. I can't do anything.

Comment: You are seeing the Windows boot manager (not the Grub menu), then after you select *Ubuntu* you have to hold down the Shift key to get the Grub menu to appear.

Comment: That's what I'm saying, it doesn't appear. It does nothing.

Comment: Sometimes grub doesn't appear - you have to tell it to run in Text mode. But to do that you have to boot Ubuntu and modify grub (or maybe boot from a USB and do it). [Reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/gfxpayload.html#gfxpayload)

Comment: I tried to boot from USB, but my BIOS doesn't have a setting to boot from USB. I'm also out of disks, so I gotta wait out the snow storm before I can buy some to try to boot from CD or DVD.

Comment: Do you have any specific reason to use 12.10! Otherwise just go for 13.04, 13.10 or 12.04 LTS(long term support) with wubi.